# Check which jar is being used by classes for compilation & execution (runtime)

Tags: java, jar, compilation, runtime

I've a very big project where thousands of classes are using 100s of third party jars.

I need to find out list of jars used by every single class in the project for compilation as well as during execution, i.e. runtime.

How can I achieve it? It is difficult to manually inspect this many classes so I would prefer some Eclipse/IntelliJ IDEA plugin which can give me a report or any type of script that can create list of classes vs jars used.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm ready close the question but didn't get why it is needs to be close? I searched a lot but didn't get any help across SE

Comment: You need this why? Just cite all of them in the classpath when compiling.

Comment: Considering SO is programming space. I'm looking for script, programs etc to create list of classes vs runtime/compiletime dependency

Comment: *"why it needs to be closed?"* The reason is: seeking recommendations for tools is off-topic.

Comment: @Olivier: OP doesn't want to know, which tool is "the best" to achieve his goal, but I think he doesn't have a clue at all, how to get such a result. To my understanding, such a question, how to achieve this goal (any hint on a suitable tool included) is well suited for SO.

Comment: Does your project consist only of one big module that has all the dependencies? I could think that this is better split up into dependencies per module, and then maybe you have a chance to find a class to dependency relation inside that module.

Comment: Actually Project4 is using Project1, Project2, Project3 as dependency jar along with other 3rd party jars(using Gradle)

Comment: Have you tried VisualVM? https://visualvm.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with IntelliJ IDEA. It's really simple.
From the main menu, select Code -> Analyze Code -> Dependencies

[image]

Then select Whole Project and press Analyse

[image]

Finaly a window open at the bottom of IDEA and on the right side you can see all  dependency used in the project.

[image]

All you have to do is navigate in your project (left part) and click on the class for which you want to know the dependency used ;)

PS: You can also Analyse only one classe to see all the dependency she used, by usong the custom scope (just select your classes)

Comment: Thanks @Louis. It shows what all packages that class is using. not really a jarName. That I can more easily do just inspecting the class import statements?

Since, my list of classes is very big, I'm looking for some programatic way to get `classes va jar` relationship printed on console.

Comment: You just have to lock at the name Java.THE_NAME and you have the jar

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add `-verbose:class` to your java command execution. This will emit any class being loaded during runtime, and the jar it was loaded from. Unlike the code analysis tool from IntelliJ, this method will also work for classes loaded using reflection.